# WCF 502 / 504 from C# client

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, azure

We have a C# client which is calling WCF service. We often get 502 / 504 exception when invoking the service from the client. We have trued on WCF trace and could not see any entries pertaining to the error and the observation of 502/504 is from fiddler. The call itself is not reaching the server. The client is behind a proxy and usually the situation occurs when we leave the client idle for 2 - 3 minutes and when a operation is tried. All the calls being made are stateless too !!. We have also checked the various timeouts Send, receive etc on web.config and app.config and seems all ok.

Another observation is that this error is not coming in a non-proxy situation, the services are hosted in cloud and from my home when i try to connect to throgh the C# application, i do not experience as i am not behind any proxy. 
(a) Is it due to the keepalive enabled by default for the WCF ? - Can we turn this off using custom binding and will it resolve the issue ? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: who is your cloud host?

Comment: Also to add, when we are experiencing the 502 / 504 - we also notice the application goes as "Not responding" and this error will popup in the clientside.

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate on why this question was downvoted?